# What is the scope of .d.ts files

Tags: reactjs, typescript, scope, next.js, .d.ts

So I am using react-table in a Typescript Next.js projects. This package consists of modules (like sorting, pagination, etc...) that aren't included by default but must be enabled in the main `useTable` hook. By default the types are set up in a way that doesn't include properties related to the modules.

I am following the following instructions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-table

Where it says to create a `react-table-config.d.ts` file and place it somewhere in my source directory and then modify it to only include the modules I need.

However while I might need some modules in one component, I might not need it in another. So I was wondering whether such files have a global scope or if it is possible to have two such files for two seperate components.

So for example if I have the following directory structure:

````
src
|
|-- components
|   |
|   |-- sorted-table
|   |   |
|   |   |-- index.tsx
|   |   |
|   |   |-- react-table-config.d.ts
|   |
|   |-- paginated-table
|   |   |
|   |   |-- index.tsx
.   .   |
.   .   |-- react-table-config.d.ts
.   .
```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need one `d.ts` file for each package defined in your `package.json`.

> However while I might need some modules in one component, I might not need it in another. So I was wondering whether such files have a global scope or if it is possible to have two such files for two seperate components.

Yes, it has global scope and it's not possible to have two `d.ts` for the same package in one project. You can put it anywhere in your project, as long as it's inside tsconfig `files` or `include`.

TypeScript will look for all `d.ts` files specified under `tsconfig.json` [files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#files), [include](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include), [exclude](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude) and map `declare` to the correct packages for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it doesn't matter where you place it if used like this

```
declare global{
//write any interface,type,etc
}
// in the end of the file
export {};
```

now you will be able to use anything from the file with out the need to import it